# Xcode 7: Cannot add Push Notification entitlement under Capabilities

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

We're upgrading our app to the next version and we're trying to add the Push Notification entitlement but we're getting the following error. **An App ID with the Identifier 'com.xxx.xxx' is not available. Pleas enter a different string.

[Screenshot of Capabilities Tab in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv9D5.png)

Also, on the General Tab is now says **None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specific capabilities: Features: Push...**

Neither of the Fix Issue button help. Please help.

[Screenshot of valid Provisioning Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp67b.png)

Comment: Have you generated Apple Push notification certificate in development mode by uploading CSR file?

Comment: @Vastal, I have generated an APNs certificate for iOS already. It's already added to my provisioning profile and the App Identifier acknowledges that it's there.

Comment: Have you added that certificate to your keychain access? Once you add the same in keychain application will ask for requesting notifications once you run the application in device.

Comment: Yes, so I ran the fastlate tools: Cert, Sigh and Pem and everything ran as per normal. As soon as I change the Bundle ID to something I've never used before it works perfectly, it's just that App ID. I've deleted and removed everything (except for App ID as app is in use) out of the developer centre and started from scratch again. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

- Check you have created the SSL certificate from **Apple developer
        site**.
- You have to add the push notification services in the certificate also.
- After the above procedures, you have to create provisional profile for you **App id**.
- Download the provisioning profile and enable the capabilities in Xcode.

Comment: Yes, all that has been done already. We have a valid developer certificate, a valid App ID, a valid Provisioning Profile and a valid APN's certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem (identical symptoms) that I assumed came from Xcode trying to use my personal developer team instead of the company developer team to which the app belonged.  There was indeed no matching bundle ID under my personal account; it was under the company team, not my personal account!

My solution was setting the push capability switch to ON (with the no matching app ID error shown below,) selecting a different code signing identity in the project settings - one that would not work at all for the app, and trying to build.  This caused the build to fail and Xcode to request to fix the (code signing identity) problem automatically.  Through some Xcode black magic, the development team in my .xcodeproj was changed to the correct team developer ID, and, more importantly, an entry for "SystemCapabilities" was added with "com.apple.Push" set to 1.  It also set my code signing identity to "iPhone Developer: My Actual Name," which had to be changed back to "iPhone Developer" to allow other people on the team to build, but the fix to push notification entitlements stayed working.

Short answer: Break something farther up the code signing process to cause Xcode to magically fix this issue.  If you can find the correct DevelopmentTeam ID, the ~10 digit alphanumeric value, replace the old entry in your .xcodeproj such as:

```
DevelopmentTeam = XYZ1234567;
```

with the correct ID and additional lines:

```
DevelopmentTeam = ABCDEFG123;
SystemCapabilities = {
    com.apple.Push = {
        enabled = 1;
    };
};
```

That's what my diff showed before and after Xcode fixed itself.